# WPF DataGrid disable a row but allow one cell

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` in WPF.
The most left cell in every row is a `CheckBox`, which sets an `Enabled` property on the row's model (through a RowViewModel).

When the `CheckBox`is unchecked on a certain row that row in the `DataGrid` should be disabled so all controls in the other columns of the row should be disabled, but not the `CheckBox` cell.

How can I easiest achieve that, still allowing the `CheckBox` cell to be enabled so the user can click the `CheckBox` in the most left cell in the row (so the user could still enable the object again hence making the complete row enabled as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a cell style that with a trigger that binds to the source property of the `CheckBox` and sets the `IsEnabled` property of the cell to `false` when the source property returns `false` or `true`:

```
<Style x:Key="cellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Enabled}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You then set the `CellStyle` property of all columns except the one with the `CheckBox` to this style:

```
<DataGridTextColumn ... CellStyle="{StaticResource cellStyle}">
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I will try this out right away.